# For which values of $a$ does the function have exactly 1 root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function is : $(a-3)9^x-6.3^x+a+5=0$ and $a$ is real. I know that if its a linear or quadratic equation with discriminant = $0$ then we have 1 root but when I set $3^x = y$ and solve the discriminant of $(a-3)y^2-6y+a+5$ to be $= 0$. I don't get the answer.

Where am I going wrong this is a high school problem and I dont't think I should be using the derivative.

Comment: What you say is true, but keep in mind that $y$ can only be positive.

Comment: One could notice that this looks a lot like $(3^x-3)^2$ then it is easy to see  $a=4$ though that need not be the only solution.

Comment: Note that if we allow complexes then $3^x<0$ leads to multiple values for $x$ (e.g. for $a=6$ and $y=-1/3$ then $x=-1+(i\pi+i2k\pi)/\ln(3)$) hence stating that we need $y>0$ is not a restriction for the problem.

Comment: @zwim As he stated that he is a high school student, I don't think that it would include complex numbers since in high school we deal with real valued functions only.I am saying this as I too am high school student and have dealt with hundreds of such problems. Although, you are correct at your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a= 3$ you don't have a quadratic since the leading coefficient must be different than $0$.

In order to have one solution either the discriminant is $0$ which should be easy enough or that you have one positive and one negative solution.

If you have one negative and one positive solution then their product is negative you can apply Vieta's formulas
$$x_1x_2=\frac{a+5}{a-3}<0$$
This happens exactly when $a\in(-5,3)$,also notice when $a=-5$ you have that $y=0$ is one solution and the other is negative but $3^x\neq 0$,and when $a=3$ we have that the quadratic is actually a linear which has one solution.So summing up you get $a\in(-5,3]\cup\{4\}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

Don't forget that $3^x$ i.e. $y$ is always positive.

So if you want any solution , all you need is positive root of this equation.

**Note** : Exactly one root must be negative else it will give two solutions or both roots must be positive and equal.

**Solution** :

Let $f(y)=(a-3)y^2-6y+a+5$.

Since we need exactly one positive solution,

$f(0)<0$ and $a-3>0$ (Coefficient of $x^2$)

Or,

$f(0)>0$ and $a-3<0$

Or,

$f(0)<0$ and $a-3>0$ AND Discriminant =0

There is one more case , when it is no more any quadratic i.e. $a=3$.In this too you'll get one positive root.

On solving for all the conditions, you will finally get :

$a \in (-5,3] \cup$ {$4$}

Comment: The answer is that and $a=4$

Comment: Also I don't understand why when $(a-3).f(0)<0$ I get only 1 root

Comment: I have solved problem for y=4, I forgot that case.See my new edit.

Comment: Can you explain why when $(a-3).f(0)<0$ I get 1 root?

Comment: @yolo expectz For that condition you can draw some graphs (of quadratic) and simply judge the conditions on y-intercept i.e. f(0) and the opening of parabola i.e. a-3.

Comment: You don't get one root, roots are always two for quadratics, by that you condition you will get one POSITIVE root.

Comment: If you still don't understand tell me and I will add images of graphs that'll help you understand.

Comment: @yolo expectz As mentioned by KingW3 you can also think this condition as : since one root is positive and one is negative , their product must also be negative, resulting in this condition.